# Fibonacci algorithm to find if a number(or a close neighbour) is the difference between 2 fibonacci numbers

Tags: algorithm, math, fibonacci

I hope that someone can help me. Given a number n (which is not necessary to be a fibonacci number), I must find if that number is equal to the difference between two fibonacci numbers, if not I must return the closest number to n, let's call it m (which is not necessary to be a fibonacci number), that is the difference between two fibonacci numbers.

I am not looking for the exact algorithm implementation but some pointers where to look at.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Combine that with the fact that the series is monotonically increasing after the first couple of terms...

Comment: I see, but let's take 29 for example which is 34 - 5, both being fibonacci numbers. If the n number is luckily a fibonacci number then the problem is solved, but in this case i can't use that property.

Comment: Aha. I was interpreting your question as between two sequential values.

Comment: I believe an exact number will also be the SUM of fibonacci numbers (21+8).  Perhaps start with greatest lesser fib and start adding backwards.

Comment: my problem explicitly states that it must be the difference not the sum

Comment: I see thank you all for the fast responses, i will try and implement @pjs's algorithm.

Comment: @CatalinIchimov I removed that comment after I realized that you might have to search through the list of all Fibonacci values below your target. That means the matrix version is not a good candidate, since it skips over unnecessary intermediate calculations. I'd suggest building an array of fibonacci values constructively, then binary searching for pair values to complete the sum for candidate values in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume without much loss of generality that `n > 0`. Since `1 = 1 - 0 = fib(1) - fib(0)`, the result `m` is positive as well. Let `0 ≤ i < j` and consider `fib(j) - fib(i)`. We have bounds

```
fib(j-2) = fib(j) - fib(j-1) ≤ fib(j) - fib(i) ≤ fib(j).
```

Therefore, for each `n`, only the possibilities with `fib(j-2) ≤ n ≤ fib(j)` need be considered. In fact, we can tighten this to `fib(j-2) < n ≤ fib(j)`, since we just as well can write `fib(j) - fib(j-1)` as `fib(j-2) - fib(0)`. Compute a logarithm/use binary search to find the two valid settings of `j`. For each setting of `j`, find the best value of `i` the same way.

Comment: thank you for your response. It will take me  little bit of time to comprehend this solution. Once i will make a draft to understand this concept i will come right back.

Answer (score 2):

What is the range n can be in?
If n is at most 2^64 then there is 93 (according to http://oeis.org/A000045/b000045.txt) fibonacci numbers that you can hold. So we have 93*93 pairs of numbers.

It's not many so you could do a 2 dimensional array of size 93x93 (which is slightly less than 10000 elements) so that every element in the array is the difference between ith and jth fibonacci number, i and j being indices of array.

Then you could put the values to a one dimensional array (you can also put there pairs of two fibonacci numbers making it if needed). Then simply sort the array by values. By performing binary search on this array you can find very fast if there exists such number n or, if not, what is the closest one to n.

You can skip making 2 dimensional array and put the values straight to one dimensional one. I put it like that so it's easier to understand and present the concept.

It probably isn't the best way to do it and it doesn't work well if n can be big but under some circumstances and when you need many tests it should be resonable method.

Comment: thank you for your response. I'm assuming you said 2^64 for long long signed int. I hope that i do not need such a high precision, i will try and implement your ideea. BRB